# When Payment is Processed with Stripe Current User is Logged Out (devise and stripe)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, stripe-payments

I am using devise for my users. In the application I have created I have the nested routes as follows:

```
     resources :programs, except: [:show] do
     resources :memberships, only: [:new, :create]
     end
```

A signed in User goes to the programs index clicks on 'Purchase Membership" and is redirected to the new_program_membership_path that Has a Stripe payment form on it. When a successful payment is processed by stripe the User get sees a Thank You response from my memberships/create.html.erb view. Where they are redircted to this view for whatever reason they appear to get logged out of the application. When I place the

```
    before_action :authenticate_user!
```

action at the top of my membership controller and a payment gets processed successfully a User gets redirected to the programs index page (instead of memberships#create) with a devise error reading "You are already logged In".

Here is my membership controller:

```
      def create
      Stripe.api_key = ENV['stripe_api_key']

      # Amount in cents
      @amount = Program.find(params[:program_id]).price*100
      @program = Program.find(params[:program_id])

      if (Program.find(params[:program_id]).price*100) < 50000
      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      :email => params[:stripeEmail],
      :description => @program.name,
      :card  => params[:stripeToken]
       )

      else
      charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      :amount => @amount, # amount in cents, again
      :currency => "usd",
      :source => params[:stripeToken],
      :description => @program.name
      )

     end

     rescue Stripe::CardError => e
     flash[:error] = e.message
     redirect_to new_program_membership_path
     end
```

here is my program_controller.rb

```
     class ProgramsController < ApplicationController
     before_action :set_program, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
     before_action :authenticate, :except => [ :index, :show ]
     # GET /programs
     # GET /programs.json
     def index
     @programs = Program.all
     @program = Program.find_by(id: params[:id])
     end

    # GET /programs/1
    # GET /programs/1.json
    def show
    end

    # GET /programs/new
    def new
    @program = Program.new
    end

   # GET /programs/1/edit
   def edit
   end

  # POST /programs
  # POST /programs.json
  def create
  @program = Program.new(program_params)

  respond_to do |format|
  if @program.save
    format.html { redirect_to programs_url, notice: 'Program was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @program }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @program.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
   end
  end

   # PATCH/PUT /programs/1
   # PATCH/PUT /programs/1.json
   def update
      respond_to do |format|
      if @program.update(program_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @program, notice: 'Program was successfully updated.' }
     format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @program }
   else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @program.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
    end
  end

     # DELETE /programs/1
     # DELETE /programs/1.json
       def destroy
         @program.destroy
            respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to programs_url, notice: 'Program was successfully destroyed.' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
      end
    end
```

What am I dong incorrectly in my code that a User would be logged out upon successfully paying with Stripe?

Comment: Can you also post the code for ProgramsController#new ? ie the method you're redirecting to?

Comment: Yes but it doesnt have anything to do with the stripe payment form, its params are just passed to the Membership form and used in the Membership controller. Should I still include it in the code

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with your stripe form code above that would cause the user to get logged out, so I'm thinking it's happening somewhere else.